# Polymer Starter Kit adding function equivalent to ready for the main page

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I've got a newly created polymer starter kit, 1.3 to be exact.

I would like to created a method like the one below, on the index.html page

```
    ready: function() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if(user) {
          // console.log('user is logged in');
        } else {
          // console.log('user is not logged in');
        }
      });
    }
```

On the main page, how can I do it? I would like to instantiate a Polymer element for the application template, but the document stays that should be avoided. If anyone could explain why that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the main page, how can I do it?

In `index.html`, you could use a [`WebComponentsReady`](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready) handler to perform any action that's dependent on all elements being registered:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
  // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
  ...
});
```

> I would like to instantiate a Polymer element for the application template, but the document stays that should be avoided.

Where did you see that? While version 1.3.0 of the Polymer Starter Kit uses an auto-binding template in `index.html` instead of an app element, I don't see why you'd try to avoid an app element. In fact, there's growing evidence that an app element is recommended:

- Version 2 of Polymer Starter Kit replaces the auto-binding template with [a custom app element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/d993ece/src/psk-app/psk-app.html)
- The dev guide describes the [Basic Application Template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/templates#basic-application-template) (generated by [`polymer-cli`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli)) as a custom element:

  > The `application` template is the most basic starting point for any app built with Polymer. It starts with a single bare-bones custom element that can serve as the root of your application, from which you can build in any direction with maximum flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the note *Note: You should only define elements from the main document when experimenting. In production, elements should always be defined in separate files and imported into your main document.* is on the https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements page.

Comment: What is *Version 2 of Polymer Starter Kit* is that the next release of the starter kit? Why is it located as a child of the normal one?

Comment: I see. That note is actually referring to declaring `<dom-module>` inside `index.html`. I typically do that in codepen/jsbin demos (mostly for convenience, but also because those services don't allow separate files unlike Plunker).

Comment: Yes, PSK2 is still in [active development](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/tree/psk2/src) and not yet released.

Comment: Do you guys find Polymers documentation scattered or less coherent then other liberty's or frameworks?

Comment: It probably depends on the library/framework you're talking about. To be fair, Polymer is relatively new and still evolving. I'm sure the Polymer team would welcome any suggestions you might have on [their GitHub issues](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues).